# How to get stable connection stream on MediaPlayer with low internet

Tags: android

I got a server with Mp3 files. In case of slow connection (2G) it takes like a minute to prepare and start, which it is unacceptable. So i would like to reduce quality of mp3's or something that reduce prepare time.

Here is the code:

```
public class Reproduce extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Boolean>{
    static  MediaPlayer mPlayer;
    static ExoPlayer exoPlayer;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        Log.d("Finish", "pre execute has finished");
        MainActivity.Loading(true);
        MainActivity.isTuched = true;
    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(String... params) {
        if(mPlayer !=null){
            if(mPlayer.isPlaying()){
                Log.d("mPlayer","isPLaying");
            }
            mPlayer.stop();
            mPlayer.release();
            mPlayer = null;
        }
        try {

            String source = params[0];
            mPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
            mPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
            mPlayer.setLooping(true);
            mPlayer.setDataSource(source);
            mPlayer.prepare();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        mPlayer.start();
        Log.d("Finish", "doin backgoud has finished");



        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: You can make the source smaller, but that's nothing to do w/ the Android client code, it's about how the file is encoded in the first place.

Comment: acctualy i did it but MediaPlayer waits to fill a default buffer size

Comment: i don't know what you are asking then. If it needs the data to play, and it can't get the data fast enough because the network is slow, you have to wait. There's no magic. Either make the source data smaller or the network faster.